# Sumatoria de diccionarios

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Estoy trabajando con **python** y **django** y tengo varios diccionarios de datos que deseo sumarlos para obtener un total. Todos los diccionarios pueden contar con dos claves `primera` y `segunda`, pero debo obtener un total tanto de `primera` como de `segunda` y un total general de ambos

```
totalinterno = {u'segunda': Decimal('1.3880'), u'primera': Decimal('18.1671')}

totalimportado = {u'segunda': Decimal('0.5000')}

totalmaquila = {u'primera': Decimal('0.3000')}
```

Quisiera obtener como resultado lo siguiente:

```
{'segunda': Decimal('1.8880'), 'primera': Decimal('18.4671')}
```

tal vez sea algo sencillo pero soy nueva en esto y no sé como hacerlo, si alguien sería tan amable de explicarme o guiarme un poco se los agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te respondió Andres, los elementos de los diccionarios pueden sumarse aritmeticamente con el método `+`:

```
from decimal import *

totalinterno = {u'segunda': Decimal('1.3880'), u'primera': Decimal('18.1671')}
totalimportado = {u'segunda': Decimal('0.5000')}
totalmaquila = {u'primera': Decimal('0.3000')}

print(totalinterno['segunda']+totalimportado['segunda'])

> 1.8880
```

Ahora, si lo que buscas es sumar el conjunto completo de los diccionarios y obtener un nuevo diccionario con los elementos actualizados, puedes usar la clase [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()
for d in [totalinterno, totalimportado, totalmaquila]: 
    counter.update(d)

print(dict(counter))
{'segunda': Decimal('1.8880'), 'primera': Decimal('18.4671')}
```

Lo que sí ten en cuenta el funcionamiento del método `+` con elementos tipo cadena, en este caso se concatenan:

```
counter.clear()
d1={'algo': 'a'}
d2={'algo': 'b'}
for d in [d1, d2]:
    counter.update(d)

print(dict(counter))
> {'algo': 'ba'}
```

Me quede pensando en algo que comentó Andrés acerca *que los diccionarios no se pueden sumar en términos matemáticos*, lo cual es cierto, pero nada nos impide crear nuestra propia clase diccionario que implemente la suma (`+`). Por ejemplo:

```
from collections import Counter

class SumarizeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,*arg,**kw):
      super(SumarizeDict, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)
      self._counter = Counter(self)

    def __add__(self, other):
      if isinstance(other, dict):
          self._counter.update(other)
          return SumarizeDict(self._counter)
      else:
        return NotImplemented

md = SumarizeDict()
print(md)
md =  md + totalinterno + totalimportado + totalmaquila
print(md)

> {}
> {'segunda': Decimal('1.8880'), 'primera': Decimal('18.4671')}
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno los diccionarios no se pueden sumar en términos matemáticos (+), así que lo que puedes hacer es sumar las claves para obtener el total, es decir, `totalinterno['primera'] + totalmaquila['primera']`, solo si estas segura de que el valor es dato numérico, en este caso veo que que tienes una función llamada "Decimal", si lo que quieres es pasarlo a decimal pues puedes optar por usar la función predeterminada de `Python` llamada `float(cadena_numero)`.